# Trying to add merchant to merchant role, user to user role

Tags: asp.net, roles

So I am using three different roles in my role manager and having trouble when I use a separate registration page for my user and one for my merchant (meaning I am not using the register page ASP.NET Identity provides, for certain reasons).

Basically I want it to function that when a merchant creates an account it gets added to the merchant role, and when a user creates and account it gets added to the user role.  Each registration method has their own separate page.  So if I figure out how to do it for one I could figure out how to do it for the other.  Been stuck on this for a few days with no results and thus I am here.  Below is the code I think you may need to help me out.

Merchant Controller (Create class), and yes I am in admin role when I do this.  The merchant will be visible under my index page that shows the list of merchants, but for some reason attaching it to the MerchantRole just isn't taking!!

```
     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MerchantID,MerchantName,State,City,StreetAddress,zip,phoneNumber,email, website")] Merchant merchant)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Merchants.Add(merchant);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
        UserManager.AddToRole("MerchantID", "Merchant");

        return View(merchant);
    }
```

My connection strings:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=        (LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=FlavorPing-2-1-alpha1;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="FlavorPingContext" connectionString="Data Source=   (localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=FlavorPingContext-20150707103956; Integrated    Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;   AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|FlavorPingContext-20150707103956.mdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     </connectionStrings><appSettings>
```

Comment: You have an if controlled by `ModelState.IsValid`, but the role addition is not happening in that branch: only when the model state is not valie.

Comment: AHH!  Alright let me fix that real quick, hope it is that easy.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't that easy.  I remember having it in the if statement before and thus I got this error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: UserId not found.

So it is not finding the USerId, is that a SYNC issue?  I notice that other DB actions have the AWAIT methods and ASYNC methods.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be?

```
UserManager.AddToRole(merchant.MerchantID, "Merchant");
```

Comment: Anytime I add merchant.MerchantID it asks me to put it in <TUSer, TKey> form.